# Wordpress - URL Structure - Passing Data

Tags: wordpress

I have a a few categories, which are the main nav links.  When a user clicks the nav link for the Category, I want to go a page that displays:

- The list of posts in that category on a sidebar
- And either a) the sticky post from that Category in a 'single entry' view OR, the 'single view' of the post the user clicked from the sidebar.

If possible, I want this all to be just one template, which seems very doable.

What Im confused about is this:

I want the url to be something like http://www.site.com/the-category/the-post

That way, I can always pull the category from the URL.  How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do this in a Category template